Pass data to custom planner plugin NAV2
(ROS2 HUMBLE)
Hi,
I created a nav2 custom planner plugin that generates a path between detected objects (specific objects).

How can I pass arguments or get data (vector of detected objects poses) to my custom planner plugin? is creating a subscriber the only way to go? is it okay to have a subscriber inside a custom planner plugin? (it seems not but I might be wrong)

When you have such scenario, when your path planning depends on object positions and not on a single goal/waypoints or robot starting position, how would you structure your behavior tree? (creating a specific navigator? or dropping the bt_navigator and using only a wrapper bt action node for the ComputePathThroughPoses and the follow path?


What's the best approach to have something modular?
Thanks.
